# Pop up animation on mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I need a popup animation on mouse hover just like this when you move over the mouse on Drive Traffic / Monetize Content / Increase Engagement: https://www.taboola.com/

Seems like CSS animation on class .cta3-items. I am not sure if it also use jQuery.

Can anyone please make a simple example of this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: I used the exact HTML and CSS from that site. CSS I used is:

.cta3-items {
  background: #3570cc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: -80px;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom 0;
  transition: all 400ms ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2000;
}

Apologies for the formatting. Not sure how to format code here. Thanks!

Comment: create a fiddle in jsfiddle.com or a snippet here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something simple, next time please post your existing code in the question description and/or link to a fiddle.

I just use CSS3 transform properties and toggle the class in jQuery.

**CSS3**

```
.flip-target {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin:center bottom;
  opacity: 0;
}

.flip-target.flip {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: translatey(-40px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#flip").click(function() {
    $(".flip-target").toggleClass("flip");
});
```

[Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/95vcp9an/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be careful in the future. Also, I can't up-vote your comment as I don't have the reputation to do so. Sorry about that.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Here's some docs for [transitions](http://https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/). Don't worry about the up vote this is a common question.

Comment: That link is awesome. Lots of things to learn. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

use animate.css css library for effect and add jqquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.yourdiv').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated youranimationname');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeCLass('animated youranimationname');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this. Also, I can't up-vote your comment as I don't have the reputation to do so. Sorry about that.

Comment: ohh that is nice my pleasure

Comment: Awesome solution, however I have as follows and it only bounces once on hover and doesn't do it again. I'd need it to bounce every time I hover over element

Comment: Ok, further to my above comment and just so anyone else doesn't struggle like I did. In the code above, "removeCLass" is spelt incorrectly. The "L" must be lower case ..  so correct spelling and case is "removeClass".